# ASP .NET Core 6 REST Api Call - IP Address vs. Domain Name

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, dns, ip

I want to call a REST Api on a database and it seems like the proceeding duration of the call itself takes much longer when I use the domain name of the target system instead of the ip.

Therefore I set up a function for getting a HTTP Client.

```
public HttpClient getHTTPclient()
{
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
    clientHandler.UseCookies = true;
    clientHandler.Proxy = null;
    clientHandler.UseProxy = false;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:8000/api/v1/");


    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", globalVariables.sCurrentCredentials);

    return client;
}
```

After that I want to call the Api.

```
using HttpResponseMessage response = await getHTTPclient().GetAsync("", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);

}
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The Call works and everything is fine but the line:

```
using HttpResponseMessage response = await getHTTPclient().GetAsync("", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

takes about 2 seconds to proceed, which is way too long. When I enter the same call into my Browser I get the result within milliseconds. I already found out that when I change the call url to an ip instead of localhost or the domain name, it will proceed with the same speed as in the browser.Can someone explain this to me? My Use case should use the domain name instead of a hardcoded ip.

Comment: Does it also make it quicker if you add a local hosts file entry for the domain name?

Comment: I did a workaround and and converted the hostname to the ip.